# Fill area of polygons with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use this part of a code to plot polygons :

```
plt.plot(x,y,'k',linewidth=2)
```

And I get this image:
[image]

I would like to fill the area of my polygons in blue, but I can't find any properties to do it... How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

you should consider using matplotlib's [polygon](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution with plt.fill() instead of plt.plot()